# Create HTML document for displaying XML stored document

Tags: html, xml, groovy

My XML doc is stored like this ...

```
<testsuite errors="0" failures="1" skipped="1" passed="1" tests="3">
    <testcase classname=postAPI name="Validate POST API" status="tested"<PASS/>>
    <testcase classname=getAPI name="Validate GET API" status="tested"<FAIL/>>
    <testcase classname=deleteAPI name="Validate DELETE API" status="untested"<SKIP/>>
   </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

I need to have a HTML document which needs to read the above XML file and I need to have the log output here in the HTML format so that the browser displays like this ...

TestCaseFeature         TestCaseName              TestCaseSTATUS

postAPI                Validate POST API          PASS

getAPI                 Validate GET API           FAIL

deleteAPI              Validate DELETE API        SKIP

How can I have such a result via HTML ?

Comment: Your XML is written incorrectly. Try this, and I'll give a response.
<testsuite errors="0" failures="1" skipped="1" passed="1" tests="3">
    <testcase classname=postAPI name="Validate POST API" status="tested" pass="true">
   </testcase>
    <testcase classname=getAPI name="Validate GET API" status="tested" pass="true">
   </testcase>
    <testcase classname=deleteAPI name="Validate DELETE API" status="untested" pass="false">
   </testcase>
</testsuite>

Comment: You write XML like HTML except they require closings for everything, even attributes.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's an answer with the XML document I added**

```
<testsuite errors="0" failures="1" skipped="1" passed="1" tests="3"> 
    <testcase classname="postAPI" name="Validate POST API" status="tested" pass="true"></testcase>
    <testcase classname="getAPI" name="Validate GET API" status="tested" pass="skip"></testcase>
    <testcase classname="deleteAPI" name="Validate DELETE API" status="untested" pass="false"></testcase> 
</testsuite>
```

**You require javascript to open XML Documents**

```
let readXMLFile = (url) => {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.body.innerHTML += "TestCaseFeature TestCaseName TestCaseSTATUS";
            for (let i = 0; i < xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('testcase').length; i++) {
                let el = xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('testcase')[i];
                let cname = el.attributes.classname.value;
                let n = el.attributes.name.value;
                let status = el.attributes.status.value;
                let pass = el.attributes.status.value;
                if (typeof pass == 'boolean') {
                    if (pass) {
                        pass = "Pass";
                    } else {
                        pass = "Fail";
                    }
                }
                let newEl = document.createElement('p');
                newEl.innerHTML = `${cname} ${n} ${pass}`;
                document.body.appendChild(newEl);
            }
        } else if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 404) {
            document.body.innerHTML = "404 Page Not Found";
        } else if (this.readyState == 4) {
            document.body.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occured! Page is loaded but cannot be sent. Contact us for help.";
        } else {
            document.body.innerHTML = '404 Page NOT Found or some other error has occured';
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

**Hope this helps!**
**Here's my page that loads it**
https://darkheart527.github.io/domain/XMLTestingPage/myFirstRequestWithAJAX.html
**Source Code**
https://github.com/DarkHeart527/domain/tree-save/gh-pages/XMLTestingPage/myFirstRequestWithAJAX.html